# Why must we declare virtual methods as such

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose we have a class, "Animal", and subclasses, "Cat" and "Dog".

Let's say we want to allow both "Cat" and "Dog" to make a noise (cat: "meow" - dog: "woof") when we pass their objects into an intermediate function for any "Animal".

Why must we use a virtual method to do this? Couldn't we just do Animal->makeNoise() without defining a virtual method in "Animal"? As "Cat" and "Dog" are both animals, wouldn't it be clear that "makeNoise()" is referring to the Animal which has been passed to the function?

Is this just a matter of syntax or something more? I'm pretty sure in Java we don't have to do this.

Comment: @Antonio, virtual base classes has absolutely nothing to do with virtual methods. It's just one of the cases when C++ does a very good job at abusing a keyword for several purposes.

Comment: What if you passed a rat that had no method `makeNoise()`.

Answer (score 10):

In Java, all member functions are `virtual` by default (except `static`, `private`, and `final` ones).

In C++, all member functions are non-`virtual` by default. Making functions `virtual` adds overhead - both runtime and to object size - and the C++ philosophy is don't pay for what you don't use. Most of my objects are not polymorphic, so I shouldn't have to pay for polymorphism unless I need it. Since you need `Animal::makeNoise()` to be `virtual`, you must explicitly specify it as such.

Comment: In Java, a `final` function can be virtual if it's non-`final` in the base class. That is, a class may override a virtual function and make it final to prevent further overrides, but it's still virtual up the hierarchy tree.

Comment: Also, you should probably mention that non-virtual functions provide not only a performance improvement, but a certain degree of safety as well. For example, calling a non-virtual function from a constructor can be safe, whereas calling virtual functions from constructors is generally a bad idea (although it isn't as bad in C++ as it is in Java).

Comment: In C++ you don't pay for what you don't use. In Java you pay for everything.

Comment: Went ahead and edited to clarify the points I mentioned earlier. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov The goal of this answer is not to enumerate everything about how `virtual` works and all of its subtleties. The goal is to simply state the high-level difference in design philosophy between C++ and Java when it comes to `virtual` defaults.

Comment: Oh, OK, sorry about that. But still, saying that `final` functions are not virtual in Java is incorrect, so maybe you could fix just that?

Answer (score 1):

C++ is designed to run with as little overhead as possible, trusting the programmer to make the correct call. Essentially, it 'gives you the gun and the option to shoot yourself in the foot', as one of my friends likes to say often. Speed and flexibility are paramount.

To correctly cause true polymorphic behavior, C++ requires it be specified. However! It is only required to be specified in the base class, as all derived class will inherit the virtual member functions. If a member inherits a virtual member function, it is good practice to place 'virtual' in the declaration, but not required.

ADTs usually implement pure virtual functions to indicate that the derived classes MUST implement the function. Such as:

```
animal makeNoise() = 0; /*Indicates this function contains no implementation.
and must be implemented by derived classes in order to function.*/
```

Again, it is not required the derived classes include 'virtual' in their inherited members so long as the base class includes this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deduce the type of the Animal and then call make_sound(), then you would have to do a dynamic_cast on the animal object for each and every child of animal. This would include any class that is directly or indirectly a child of the Animal class.

This is both difficult to maintain and very painful to any change eg. Adding new class as a child to the Animal class.

Since c++ philosophy is efficiency, you will have to ask the compiler to provide you with run-time polymorphism as it is costly. How would you do that? By stating the make_sound() function as virtual. This creates a vtable ( a table of functions pointers ) which refers to an address of make_sound() which differs to based on the type of the object.

No need to downcast as indirection handles everything for you. What could be hundreds of lines of code is just a single line of code. That is the power of indirection!!

Answer (score 0):

In java you use virtual methods too.
It improves the loosely coupling of your software.

For example, you can use a library and don't know which animal they use internally. There is a animal implementation you don't know and you can use it because it's an animal. You get the animal with a library.getAnimal method. Now you can use their animal without to know which noise it makes, because they have to implement the method makeNoise.

Edit: So to answer your question, c++ wants a explicit declaration and in java it is implicit. so yes it is a kind of language specific idiosyncracy.

Comment: In Java you don't do this and can't do this. You can't *declare* a virtual function as such because there is no such keyword in Java.

Comment: so you can't override a parent method in java? Java public methods are virtual by default imho

Comment: That's right. And since they are virtual by default, you can't *declare* them as virtual nor do you need to do so. Read the question carefully.

Comment: never said you declare something, I said you also use virtual methods in java

Comment: You start your answer with “In java you do this too”, but the question reads as “Why must we declare virtual methods as such”. The OP obviously wants to know why virtual methods must be declared as `virtual` in C++, while in Java you don't have to do this—they will be virtual anyway.

Comment: Ah now I know what you mean.
I was refering to it's statement that in java we don't do this. 

I should change my post and say, it's because c++ wants a explicit declaration and in java it is implicit. so yes it is a kind of language specific idiosyncracy

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you have to do it because that's one of the rules of the language.

There's a reason its helpful though.

When trying to validate the code that uses an Animal, the complier knows what functions exist on an Animal. Its possible to tell whether the code is correct without checking all classes that derive from animal. So that code doesn't need to depend on all those derived classes. If you derive a new class from Animal but forget to implement the makeNoise function that's an error in the new class not the code that uses the Animal base class and the complier can point you towards that error. Without the virtual function declared in Animal there would no way to tell if its the calling code or the new class that is in error.

A key point here is that these errors would be caught at compile-time for C++ because of its static typing. Other languages can allow dynamic typing, which can make some things easier but, the errors would only be spotted at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all functions are virtual by default. In C++ they are not, so when you call a non-virtual function on a pointer of a given type, that type's implementation of that function is invoked with the object's address as `this`.

```
class Animal {
public:
    void sound() { std::cout << "splat\n"; }
    virtual void appearance() { std::cout << "animaly\n"; }
};

class Cat {
public:
    void sound() { std::cout << "meow\n"; }
    virtual void appearance() { std::cout << "furry\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Animal a;
    Cat c;
    Animal* ac = new Cat;

    a.sound();  // splat
    a.appearance();  // animaly

    c.sound();  // meow
    c.appearance();  // furry

    ac->sound();  // splat
    ac->appearance();  // furry
}
```

This would occur when you wanted to write a function that generalized on "Animal" rather than requiring a specific derived class pointer.